# Excel Powerpivot Dax(not native excel)- convert time to decimal hours

Tags: excel, time, powerpivot, dax

I have a list of times:

```
8:30PM
8:15PM
7:20PM
```

How can I convert these to decimal hours in Powerpivot (DAX)?

for example:

```
8.5
8.25
7.33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula `DecimalNumber = Sheet1[DATE]*24`, or simply multiply your time with 24. 8:30PM can never evaluate to 8:30 since it is PM, so it's actually 20:50. If you want it to be 8:50 instead, then subtract 12 from formula.

[image]